# Rotate UIBarButtonItem Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

In Swift, I have a hamburger bar button, so when tapped I want that hamburger Bar button to rotate 90 degrees (so that the lines are vertical) and then when you click it again I would like it to go back to it's original state (horizontal)

NOTE: Can you make sure that this works for a UIBarButtonItem, because some solution to a normal UIButton does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a `UIButton` inside of `UIBarButtonItem` to achieve this, and a variable with state vertical or not

**this is my storyboard setup**
[image]

**Here is the code of simple view controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isVertical : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func rotateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if(!self.isVertical)
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                self.isVertical = true
            })
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform.identity
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                self.isVertical = false
            })
        }

    }


}
```

**Result**

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!! I did exactly what you did and the animation works beautifully! Unfortunately there is one problem, when you click on the hamburger it doesn't open up the side view like it used to. And when I try to set up the animation the same way on the other screens which are accessed by the side menu it gives an error and says "Value of type 'AboutWhoKnew' has no member 'isVertical' " (AboutWhoKnew is the name of a swift file). Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: What I had before which opened up the side menu was an IBOutlet of the UIBarButtonItem hamburger which in each of the swift files that were connected to each view controller I put in the viewDidLoad() "hamburger.target = self.revealViewController()" and "hamburger.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))"

Comment: @C.Elam did you solve your problem?, you can add this in your base viewController and then must work in all your application, you can also define a custom UIButton class and define de property isVertical there, if you need help let me know, please accept my answer, best regards

Comment: No I didn’t solve my problem. I’m a little confused on what you just said, can you explain? So what I had had before I added this whole thing to make it vertical was an IBOutlet called hamburger and then in the viewDidLoad() I have the code that I previously typed in the other comment and everything worked and it did the revealViewController. But anyway, how do I make this (the code you gave me) revealViewController.

Comment: So I ended up fixing one of my problems the one where it was giving me the error when I set it up on the other view controllers. Unfortunately I am not sure how to make it so that when you click the button it revealsViewController?

Comment: @C.Elam I am glad, you finally figured out,  congrats!

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func rotateAction1(_ sender: Any) {
    if (!self.isVertical) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)
        }, completion: {
            (finished) in
            self.isVertical = true

        })

        revealViewController().revealToggle(true)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: {
            (finished) in
            self.isVertical = false
        })
        revealViewController().revealToggle(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe is better put `revealViewController().revealToggle(false)` and `revealViewController().revealToggle(true)` inside animation ends blocks must work even better waiting until animation ends to show  and hide your side menu, but its up to you

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
func rotateBarButton() {

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)) // Create new button & set its frame
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings"), for: UIControlState()) // Assign an image
        let lef = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = lef// Set as barButton's customView

        // Gets you half way there //
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
        }, completion: nil)
        // Rotates all the way around //
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```