# Animate (Rotate) UIBarButtonItem custom buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

All I want to do is rotating the UIBarButtonItem when it is clicked.

I followed this post [Rotate UIBarButtonItem Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856773/rotate-uibarbuttonitem-swift), but it is not working.

The difference is:

[image]

1- I set the image on runtime when view is loaded:

```
     showHideBtn.image = showHeaderimage
```

2- I have two buttons in my right Bar button items:

Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func rotateAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if(!self.isVertical)
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            self.isVertical = true
        })
    }else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            self.isVertical = false
        })
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Updated code:

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     if(!self.isVertical) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)
        }, completion: { (finished) in
           self.isVertical = true
        })


    }else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)
        }, completion: { (finished) in
           self.isVertical = false
        })

    } }
```

Show button property:

[image]

Comment: try adding `DispatchQueue.main.async {`  before the first if and close it before the last  }. I know that `@IBAction` is called on main thread but I've seen lately a lot people having problems when updating UI inside a `@IBAction` and usually dispatch it on main fix it.

Comment: @IonescuVlad I tried, and it is not working

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Koen the UIBarButtonItem is not rotating

Comment: Did you step through the code?

Comment: @koen yes and I debug it , it is correctly called but no effect to the uibarbutton.  I update my code in the post

Comment: @Koen I think the error is in :  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem? cz since I have two buttons , how he will know the difference?

Comment: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)` is not transforming because `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView == nil`. Look at your view outline compared to the one you linked. Notice that there's another layer to their right bar button item entitled "Button."

Comment: Depends on how you add the buttons to your UI. You can access them through `rightBarButtonItems`, the pick the one you need.

Comment: @beyowulf i am a bit confused , yes indeed I print the value of self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView  and it is nil, but I don't know why and how to fix it

Comment: @Wael if you would like to do it in code you can follow @Glaphi's answer. Setting it up in a storyboard, I suspect you dragged a `UIBarButtonItem` in your navigation bar rather than a plain old `UIButton` which Xcode will automatically create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIButton` set to its `customView` property.

Comment: @beyowulf I found why it is not working it I used the storyboard but dunno how to fixed it ,   it look like that the UIbutton must be the first button on the right, if it not the case it will not work (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView return nil)

Comment: You can use `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` which will return an array of `UIBarButtons` you can loop over them and find the button you desire.

Comment: @beyowulf 10x man, it work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be how you've set the custom view in the bar item. Maybe this `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.` is returning nil. Anyway, here is a working version:

**Creating the custom UIBarButtonItem:**

```
let button1: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))

let button2: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))

override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
    button1.backgroundColor = .gray
    button1.setTitle("CustomButton", for: .normal)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotateAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let barItem1: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)

    button2.backgroundColor = .gray
    button2.setTitle("CustomButton", for: .normal)
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotateAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let barItem2: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)

    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([barItem1, barItem2], animated: true)
}
```

**Animate the tapped button:**

```
@objc func rotateAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let customView = sender

    let transform: CGAffineTransform = isVertical ? .identity : CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * .pi / 180)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        customView.transform =  transform
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        self.isVertical = !self.isVertical
    })
}
```

To avoid replacing the bar button item/items set from storyboard, get those button items and create an array of bar button item including those with the ones you created in code:

```
let existingBarItems: [UIBarButtonItem] = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems ?? []
let rightBarItems = existingBarItems = [yourCustomButtonItem]
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(rightBarItems, animated: true)
```

And make sure your custom bar button item's frame doesn't intersect with existing buttons.

Comment: @Glaphi your solution worked but it replace the done button instead to be next to it, how to solve that? thank you. ( the "Done" is created via storyboard and not on runtime)

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look and let me know if I'm missing anything @Wael

Comment: @Glaphi it work man thank you. but I keep digging why it is not working via storyboard , I DragDrop a uibutton and still not working.

Comment: You're welcome!, you can mark the answer correct if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @Glaphi I found why but I don't know how to fixe it, it look like that the UIbutton must be the first button on the right, if it not the case it will not work (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView return nil)